# Facing this issue when connecting php with mysql in mac

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysql-workbench

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password] in /Library/WebServer/Documents/test.php on line 30
>
> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client in /Library/WebServer/Documents/test.php on line 30
> Unable to Connect to '127.0.0.1'

Comment: Can you show your `test.php` script?

Comment: <form>
Hobbies:<input type="checkbox" name="Hobbies1">Reading
<input type="checkbox" name="Hobbies2">Travelling
<input type="checkbox" name="Hobbies3">Swimming<br><br>
</form>
<button type="button" name="submit" (click)="clickAlert()">submit</button>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$database = "testing";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($localhost, $username, $password);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
  echo "Connected successfully";
?>